# How to "loop" back to a certain function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, loops, click

I am trying to understand how to **run a function**, then run a **second function**... then **return to the original function**. (a loop?)

As you can see in my fiddle:  ...I am trying to get the bloke to walk right **on click**, **when clicked a second time** he walks back to the original position. **When clicked a third time**, I want him to **continue the pattern**.... (eg. Right, Left, Right, Left...)

This is for a point and click game I am working on (a goal [motivation] to learn jquery/javascript).

I appreciate your help and patience on this. Sorry for the n00b code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".img").one("click", function() {
        $(".img").attr('src', "http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/walking.gif");
        $(".img").animate({
            "left": "+=300px"
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(".img").attr('src', "http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/standing.gif");
            $(".img").click(function() {
                $(".img").attr('src', "http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/walkingLeft.gif");
                $(".img").animate({
                    "left": "-=300px"
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(".img").attr('src', "http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/standing.gif");
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/testsubject1203b/68epJ/32/

Comment: Add jsfiddle in your question instead of comment.

Comment: Accept answers please, will encourage people to answer your questions in future

Answer (score 3):

Use a `.toggle()`,

So your code will look like this,

```
$(".img").toggle(function(){

    //Code to go right

}, function(){

    //Code to go left

});
```

Read about [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: If I were to throw other functions into this, ( walk right, walk left, walk right, walk up)  would this method work? (Does toggle work with more than one function?)

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Will test and respond if any issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle is good and it works too I have done a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68epJ/163/).

But i have found another solution for those who don't want to use toggle.I know its a time consuming one w.r.t to toogle usage but i thought of sharing it here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=1
    $(".img").click("click", function(){

    count=count+1;
if(count%2==0)
{

$(".img").attr('src',"http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/walking.gif");
    $(".img").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, 1000, function() {



        $(".img").attr('src',"http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/standing.gif");
    });
}
else
{

$(".img").attr('src',"http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/walkingLeft.gif");
              $(".img").animate({"left": "-=300px"}, 1000, function() {
            $(".img").attr('src',"http://www.kolbaba.com/uploads/jsfiddle/tempImgs/standing.gif");
              });
}


    });
```

});